# Offline video streaming

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video, offline

I am fairly certain I have been asked to do the impossible. My stakeholders want to  be able to set videos in our platform to be available offline on our website. Basically the user would be able to trip a flag on the player to make the video cache locally.

I can find all manner of ways to make the page itself function more or less well offline, but nothing to make the videos work. Also, they do not want the user to be able to copy, play or otherwise interact with the video file outside of our platform.

I am pretty sure this is impossible, and would love to tell them so, but can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1):

Several DRM systems support a 'download' and go mode which will allow you achieve what you are looking for here.

Your users can download the video while online and request the licence key, and play it even when offline.

Different DRM's support diffrent OS's and devices to varying degrees - for example Widevine Modular (Google) has this functionality on Android devices but not for web, PlayReady (Microsoft) supports offline playback with persistent licences and there is quite a bit of demand towards FairPlay (Apple) to also support offline mode and persistent licenses.

Comment: They do not want to use DRM, and they only want the videos to play inside the web page. I've pretty much convinced them it cannot be done.